# Does this SFINAE pattern have a name?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, sfinae

Operating under the rule of "there's never anything new under the sun," I doubt that I'm the first person to come up with this trick.  I figured I would stumble across something online documenting it eventually, but I haven't yet, so I figured I would ask.

Its purpose is to selectively enable certain functions provided that they're relevant, without using a derived class.

Is there a name for this pattern?  And does anyone have any useful information on this pattern or a pattern that operates similarly?

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Point {
public:
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable2D = typename std::enable_if<P == 2 && N == P, T2>::type;
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable3D = typename std::enable_if<P == 3 && N == P, T2>::type;
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable4D = typename std::enable_if<P == 4 && N == P, T2>::type;
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable2DOrHigher = typename std::enable_if<P >= 2 && N == P, T2>::type;
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable3DOrHigher = typename std::enable_if<P >= 3 && N == P, T2>::type;
  template<size_t P, typename T2=void>
  using Enable4DOrHigher = typename std::enable_if<P >= 4 && N == P, T2>::type;

  //Example use cases
  template<size_t P=N>
  static Enable2D<P, Point> withAngle(T angle, T magnitude = 1);
  template<size_t P=N>
  static Enable3D<P, Point> fromAngles(T psi, T theta, T magnitude = 1);

  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable2DOrHigher<P, T> const& x() const;
  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable2DOrHigher<P, T> const& y() const;
  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable2DOrHigher<P> setX(T const& t);
  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable2DOrHigher<P> setY(T const& t);

  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable3DOrHigher<P, T> const& z() const;
  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable3DOrHigher<P> setZ(T const& t);

  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable4DOrHigher<P, T> const& w() const;
  template<size_t P=N>
  Enable4DOrHigher<P> setW(T const& t);
};
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea -- essentially parameterizing the member function pointers. In javascript, you can build the "prototype" object and thereby conditionally create certain member functions. I haven't seen anything similar in C++.  Curious to see replies...

Comment: The motivating use case for this was we also had multi-dimensional line and box classes that took a standard point, but we had previous had derived classes for point2 and point3, so the useful 2d and 3d point functions were not accessible both to the classes themselves (unless we were to derive those too, in which case it would be a reimplementation because the members had changed and there was a lot of common code, DRY), but also to any piece of code that used the box and line algorithms.  So we felt that using SFINAE was cleaner, even if it made the exposed functions slightly inconsistent.

Comment: Why should repeated use of `enable_if` become a pattern?  This is a typical application of `enable_if` - e.g. consider [cppreference's description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) "*conditionally remove functions and classes from overload resolution based on type traits and to provide separate function overloads and specializations for different type traits*"... seems to encompass what you've done entirely adequately.

Comment: @TonyD, specifically it's the `enable_if<some condition && default parameter == class parameter>` combined with `template<default parameter=class parameter>`.  (To use a class parameter as an argument to an inner template to trigger SFINAE, without invalidating the whole class, but also to protect against manually specifying wrong values.)  I mean, it's nothing revolutionary certainly, like the CRTP isn't horribly complicated, but it is a pattern.

Comment: I've done this before: https://ideone.com/jLCjvz

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, awesome, came up with it by yourself?  Or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: I came up with it when I was trying to write a sort of type-safe `boost::any` / `boost::variant`. Didn't want all the type-erasure stuff. Was also working with boxes and lines and points like you. Then I decided to try to make one container for all and that's how I came up with trying double and tripple nested/stacked templates. Didn't give compile errors so I didn't bother searching why it worked lol. Good question though. Hope to see replies soon.

Comment: After searching `std::generic_container` in google.. Codeblocks was showing that as a suggestion when I tried compiling my class above.. It is known as coercion? Or similar http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Coercion_by_Member_Template

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: well, if you find a name and - armed with that - find a significant number of mentions of it, then you're right :D.  Failing that there's the future....

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it, that's specifically for type coercion in type encapsulating classes.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: coercsion is implicit type conversion, as happens when you do something like `my_int + my_double` and `my_int` is first converted to `double`.

Comment: I've done something similar, but without `enable_if`. My own tuple type with element types `E...` derives class [`access<D, E...>`](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/tuple/base/access.hpp) where `D` is the derived class (the tuple). With two specializations provided for `access`, tuples of one element have a member `val()`, tuples of two elements have members `fst()`, `snd()` (like `first`, `second` in `std::pair`). This is the same effect as your `x()`, `y()`, etc. Plus, `access` can be plugged as a base of any type (there are dozens of tuple specializations).

Comment: @iavr Yep me too, but without alias templates and (shame on me) with the use of macros to generate the signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a pattern, but it's a known technique.

Mostly reffered to as **conditional interface** this technique mainly addresses the problem of a compile time toggling mechanism to switch on and off interfaces of a class. The overall process provides the tools to also toggle the existence of members (so the term **conditional compilation** gets born).

The technique is more or less implemented the way you propose (though the lack of alias templates was not a problem prior to c++11) and the usual problem is the heavy, cluttering, confusing and "ugly" template machinery boilerplate code.

Addressing this issue, **A. Alexandrescu** [**gave a presentation**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer) about the topic. Initially there's a small mentioning of the needs for such a technique :

[image]

The bullet that says

- This function works only with numbers

is reffering to your techniques and the need to have compile time conditionals to toggle the existence of functions ( conditional interface ).

The talk goes on to a proposal for *a new language feature*. Since we all invented the wheel a couple of times he says, why not a new language syntax, that will allow us to perform such things. His [**joint work**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf) with **H. Sutter**, produced **`static if`** a compile time toggler that would remove the needs for workarounds as the one you mention. A simple use of this would be

```
template<int D>
struct Vector
{
    double coordinates[D];
    static if ( D ) {
        double x() { return coordinates[0]; }
    }
    static if ( D > 1 ) {
        double y() { return coordinates[1]; }
    }
    static if ( D > 2 ) {
        double z() { return coordinates[2]; }
    }
};
```

OK maybe that's not the smartest use of it but I think I'm communicating the idea.

On the opposing side now, **B. Stroustroup** has published a [**paper**](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3613.pdf) where after aknowledging the problems `static if` is addressing, he explains why it's a flawed concept (pun intended :) ) and its adoption would be a disaster for the language (ouch!).

That was my two cents, judging from the level of the participants in this "conversation" I'd like to have some feedback regarding on which side they're on, or if they're part of the standardization process what will they be voting for.

Comment: I don't know much history, but maybe it was then that Alexandrescu decided to go on and do it [the D way](http://dlang.org/cpptod.html#metatemplates)...